# Why my iPhone OpenGL-ES texture does not cover the viewport?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, vertex-shader

I have a square image of size 320x320, from which I create an OpenGL texture. I use the most basic Vertext and Fragment shaders and I want to display the texture in the entire view. The view (EAGLView derived from UIView as found in many OpenGL iOS samples) is also of size 320x320.

The problem is, the image is drawn on the top left corner, covering only around 50% of the entire view. It does not cover 100% of the view. I don't know why?

[image: Red square is EAGLView]

Here is my code:

```
position = glGetAttribLocation(m_shaderProgram, "position");
inputTextureCoordinate = glGetAttribLocation(m_shaderProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");    
inputImageTexture = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram, "inputImageTexture");

static const GLfloat textureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};

static const GLfloat imageVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
};

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight); // These are 320, 320

glUseProgram(m_shaderProgram);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sourceTextureID); // The texture is also of size 320x320

glUniform1i(inputImageTexture, 2);  

glVertexAttribPointer(position, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, imageVertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinate, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureCoordinates);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);    
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

Vertext Shader.

```
 attribute vec4 position;
 attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

 varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

 void main()
 {
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
 }
```

Fragment Shader.

```
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 void main()
 {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);
 }
```

Comment: did you take into consideration that the iphone 4 and up have 2x scale factor? (try rendering it twice as big to make up for the retina display)

Comment: I tried with different dimensions, other than 320. But the result is the same. I am using 320 here just for the example.

Comment: do you mean you already tried changing the viewport? cuz that should definitively make it look bigger or smaller

Comment: I set the EAGLView's frame size and view port's size to the size of the texture, i.e. 320x320 in this case. However I can make the texture draw fit to the view size by manually adjusting the viewport size or using a numbers smaller than 1.0 in the textureCoordinates. But that does not make sense as I still do not understand what exactly is the problem here. Or how shall I adjust the view port size or texture coordinates without hardcoding them.

Comment: I guess I got the problem. The texture's dimensions need to be power of 2, for example if I use 1024x1024, the problem goes away. If my texture is of size not 2's power, I think I will have to adjust the texture coordinate's. Instead of 1.0 as the texture's edge, it will be a smaller number, the ration of the dimension to the next nearest 2's power. I have't tried this yet. I will update it soon.

Comment: Yes for opengl to properly do textures it has to be powers of 2. I thought you were not trying it in this way but still this should not affect it because if you use the correct texture opengl should strech it. did you see what texture properties did you set up?

Comment: This is the code that I use to create the texture...


glGenTextures(1, &texID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

It would be nice if I could make it stretch by setting some property?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem is that the texture's dimensions were not 2's power. So we need to scale the textureCoordinates accordingly. Inserting following lines solved the problem...

```
GLfloat textureCoordinates[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,  0.0f,
    1.0f,  0.0f,
};

float nearest2sPower = 2;

if (nearest2sPower < backingWidth) {
    while (nearest2sPower < backingWidth) {
        nearest2sPower *= 2;
    }
}

verticalFlipTextureCoordinates[2] = backingWidth/nearest2sPower;
verticalFlipTextureCoordinates[6] = backingWidth/nearest2sPower;

nearest2sPower = 2;

if (nearest2sPower < backingWidth) {
    while (nearest2sPower < backingWidth) {
        nearest2sPower *= 2;
    }
}

verticalFlipTextureCoordinates[1] = backingHeight/nearest2sPower;
verticalFlipTextureCoordinates[3] = backingHeight/nearest2sPower;
```

Comment: While this is pretty much certainly the right answer, it'll depend on exactly how the poster uploaded the texture. Most pre-packaged solutions are going to round up to the nearest power of two but if memory serves then ES 2.0 doesn't actually require it.

Comment: This really shouldn't be required, so I don't think this is the real solution to the issue. All iOS devices that support OpenGL ES 2.0 also support non-power-of-two textures (with some slight limitations for clamping modes and use of mipmaps). If it was a true non-power-of-two error with the texture upload, you just would get a black image (trust me, I've made this mistake on more than one occasion).

Comment: @Tommy and Brad, It was a silly mistake on my part. Actually I copied some code that creates texture from an UIImage. And that code internally creates textures to the "next nearest power of two" width and height. So, effectively I was nullifying the extra width and height with my code. Sorry about the wrong answer. That code is not required.